# How to check view is visible in scrollView centre and perform action

Tags: swiftui

For example, I have created a scrollView contained LazyVStack for displaying the label.[Example UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsHrg.png)

How can I check if the cell is visible in ScrollView centre and perform some action to the cell.
[Text (Name 9) in scrollView centre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4LgT.png)

For example, user is scrolling, when Name 9 label is visible to scrollView centre, the label font size change to 30.

Code Update:
[Update code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WP10.png)

Answer (score 2):

In scroll view SwiftUI. You could check if the center by triggering `.onAppear` of the item inside scroll view(It seems a cheat but it's true).

```swift
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(listContents) { item in
                     SomeView(item)
                    .onAppear {
                        if (item.index == kCenterPosition) {
                           // DoSomething With Center Scroll List Apear
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

You also auto trigger to center scroll view by the way:

```
ScrollViewReader { proxy in
  List { ...
  }
  .onApear {
    proxy.scrollTo(listContents[someValue], anchor: .center)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank for answering, kCenterPosition is represent for ?

Comment: it's a valuable example of the position you want to move, It could be the center of an array index item

Answer (score 1):

if you want to know if the given element is visible or in the center of the scrollview you will need to wrap each element inside a scroll with a `GeometryReader` of its own. I've taken your code snipped and given the functionality you are asking for, also added comments in the code itself for clearance

```
    @State var model = [
        "name 1", "name 2", "name 3", "name 4",
        "name 5", "name 6", "name 7", "name 8",
        "name 9", "name 10", "name 11", "name 12",
        "name 13", "name 14", "name 15", "name 16",
        "name 17", "name 18", "name 19", "name 20",
        "name 21", "name 22", "name 23", "name 24"
    ]
    
    @State var middleName: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach (self.model, id: \.self) { name in
                        // wrap inner view in geometry reader so you can get its coordinates relative to the scrollView
                        GeometryReader { inner in
                            Text(name)
                                .font(.system(size: name == middleName ? 30 : 18))
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                                .onChange(of: inner.frame(in: .global).midY) { y in // you can use midY, minY or maxY depending on your case
                                    let threshold: CGFloat = 20 // adjust this to the precision of "middle" to your liking
                                    let screenMid = proxy.size.height / 2 // you can get the middle point of any view if you have outter geometry reader like in this snippet
                                    if y > screenMid - threshold && y < screenMid + threshold {
                                        // do something, you can update @State properties
                                        // to reflect changes when this view gets in the middle
                                        print("is in middle: \(name)")
                                        middleName = name
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                        .frame(height: 100)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

if you just want to know about which elements are visible you would just need to update the math in `.onChange(of:)` method and have @State properties fitting your own case. For experimenting and figuring out the exact values it is possible to have Text variables printing those GeometryProxy content.

Answer (score 0):

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
ScrollView { 
   // ur 9th cell
.font(.system(size: self.isInMiddleOfScreen(geometry) ? 30 : 10))
  }
}

private func isInMiddleOfScreen(_ geometry: GeometryProxy) -> Bool {
if geometry.frame(in: .global).maxY <= UIScreen.main.bounds.height {
return true
}
return false
}
```

Comment: Thank for you reply, I have tried the code but all cell font size updated to 30. I have updated my code, what did i do wrong?